# sending a php variable to onclick event

Tags: php, javascript

can i send a php variable to my javascript function using onclick event of a link like this

```
<a onclick="change(<?php echo $description ?>)">
```

when I echo the description it is available but when I send it to my javascript function it says undefined

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Use a JSON encoding routine to encode the description. That'll add quotes and check for embedded quotes.

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode($description); ?>`

Comment: not working :( i get an empty alet inside my javascript function

Answer (score 3):

`$description` is probably a string, so you need quotes around it in your Javascript:

```
<a onclick="change('<?php echo $description ?>')">
```

Comment: Also take a look at "Unobtrusive Javascript". It is better to separate your Javascript from your HTML

Comment: Since we can't see your output, "not working" is not enough information for us to provide useful answers. Please update your question or your comment to provide full details: what do you expect to happen, what you tried (exactly), and what really happened (errors, etc).

Comment: I have just a javascript function change 
function change(desc) alert(desc) nothing else in javascript

Comment: Do `<?php var_dump($description); ?>` and tell us what it says

Comment: @George Cummins It is not showing me the alert in which i want to display the description. when I use hardcoded string it shows the alert... I think there is some problem in the data that comes from the database... It contains some html tags when it comes from database can I remove all the tags first and then pass the string only ?

Comment: Yes, [`strip_tags()`](http://us.php.net/strip_tags) will do that for you. However, you should check the Javascript console for errors and post those.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this in jquery.. if you're interested in using another library such as jquery..

### Js

```
var description;
$('#description').click(function(){
  description = $(this).val();
  //alternatively you can use data-description and retrieve it like so:
  description = $(this).data('description');
  //if that doesnt work use attr();
  description = $(this).attr('data-description');
  //this will return "My awesome description"
  console.log(description);
}
```

### php

```
<?php 
$description = 'My awesome description';
?>
```

### html

```
<a id="description" href="#"><?= $description; ?></a>
<!-- alternatively you could used data-description attribute on the href and pass that.. -->
<a href="#" data-description="<?= $description; ?>">Link 1</a>
```